# is it possible put image in input type="check box"?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

i want to put an image on the background of check box & radio box in my html code but it's not work but it's work on other form property.

Comment: I think its not possible, you can try some javascript+css work for that. Example: http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to help you if you provided at least some of the code related to where you're having a problem.

Comment: You can try if you can build something out of `input[type=checkbox]:after` and `input[type=checkbox]:checked:after`, but that's probably CSS3 and I don't have complete boiletplate for that, sorry.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the way how give image to **checkbox** & **radio** button with pure css.

**HTML**

```
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    background: #999;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: #0080FF;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Check this for more http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/ ,

https://gist.github.com/592332

Answer (score 3):

I write my own code to fix this issue. This will work like this. I didn't have this code now but I write same way here on SO.

```
<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
<input type="checkbox" name="value"/>
<img src="img/blah.png"/>
</div>
```

In css we will hide this checkbox by make it's Z-index less then the image that I put inside this wrapper code. Eventwise when someone click on image it's look like checkbox and in real checkbox will be clicked. instead of `display:none` using `opacity:`0 will be better. This will break in IE6 but we didn't care about that because I am not supporting IE6 anymore.

In Javascript You can write event if you want a different (but similar to mine) implementation. You can replace native Html Checkbox,Radio and select (select2 is better if you stick with Twitter bootstrap) with your own themes based controls.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I made an example of **"Use Images Like Checkboxes and Radios Pure Css"**

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gh5kdp?file=index.html)

```css
* {
  font-family: Lato;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  --transition: 0.15s;
  --border-radius: 0.5rem;
  --background: #ffc107;
  --box-shadow: #ffc107;
}

.cont-bg {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle farthest-corner at 7.2% 13.6%,
    rgba(37, 249, 245, 1) 0%,
    rgba(8, 70, 218, 1) 90%
  );
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.cont-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-checkbox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  background: white;
  transition: transform var(--transition);
}

.cont-checkbox:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  margin-right: 0.75rem;
}

.cont-checkbox:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--background);
}

input:checked + label img {
  -webkit-filter: none; /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: none;
}

input:checked + label .cover-checkbox {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

input:checked + label .cover-checkbox svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

label img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  object-fit: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 81%, 50% 100%, 0 81%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

label .cover-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--box-shadow);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: transform var(--transition),
    opacity calc(var(--transition) * 1.2) linear;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

label .cover-checkbox svg {
  width: 13px;
  height: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  fill: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0 3px;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.4s ease var(--transition);
  stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
}

label .info {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-bg">
  <div class="cont-title">Checkbox</div>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox-1" />
      <label for="myCheckbox-1">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Mazda MX-5 Miata</div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox-2" />
      <label for="myCheckbox-2">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Toyota Supra</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cont-title">Radio</div>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio-1" />
      <label for="myRadio-1">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Mazda MX-5 Miata</div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio-2" />
      <label for="myRadio-2">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Toyota Supra</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the checkbox in a div, and place a background image in said div. Here's an example:

```
<div id="backgrounddiv" style="background-image: url('image.gif');">
<input id="check_box" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: I didnt try this but just from the look I can see this wont work for our purposes :) , sandeep's own solution is the best :) (yet)