# Style radio button with custom images

Tags: html, css, image, radio-button

How can I remove classic circle of radio button and use instead a custom icon?
Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: The icons are dependent of the option value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible put image in input type="check box"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790281/is-it-possible-put-image-in-input-type-check-box)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [Uniform](https://github.com/fidian/uniform). Its a nice and easy way to have complete design  control over form elements. Indeed it does require JavaScript but if its not enabled by default Uniform degrades gracefully offering the standard form functionality.