# CakePHP 3 image click information and the form

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm having a standard form and some images on the page distributed at random places at the page. I would like to select and click one of the images, add some information to the inputs and then click submit button. The problem is that I have no good solution for sending an information through the form about the fact which image randomly distributed was clicked. My only idea was to make images url but then I cannot pass information from the inputs. Any good suggestion of how can I combine which image was clicked with the standard form information?

Comment: Is it not possible to add click event listener on your images, and on click you save the inforrmation in a hidden input field?

Comment: Can you please present a simple example of your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, here is a sample form which contains a hidden field:

```
    <form>
         <input type="hidden" name="image_info" >
         <!-- you other input fields -->
         <input type="text" name=".." >
         ...
         ...
   </form>
```

and in your **HTML** you have different image tag
like

```
<img src="..." data-info="image info to be placed in hidden field" title="..." alt="..." />
<img src="..." data-info="image info to be placed in hidden field" title="..." alt="..." />
```

and in **Javascript**

```
<script>
 $('img').on('click', function() {
   var img = $(this),
       img_field = $('input[name=image_info]');

   img_field .val(img.data('info') );
 });
</script>
```

It's not a complete code, but an idea how you can implement it.

Comment: I understand what you mean now but it is not a solution for me because I cannot use javascript for a crutial functionality. And here is indeed an important and crutial functionality. +1point for the idea but still not a solution for me

Comment: @Annabelle JS is by far the most simple and flexible solution, given that the images can be placed anywhere in the DOM that way. Non-JS solutions are either annoyingly complicated and involve frames, sessions, additional server side processing, etc, or require placing the images inside of the form, and [**turning them into checkboxes or radio buttons**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790281/is-it-possible-put-image-in-input-type-check-box).

Comment: Yes, very unwillingly but I just finished this functionality using hidden inputs and JS. How safe is it to use session for this matter? Is it better to use session in this case?

Comment: @Annabelle Client data in never safe, even your input fields, you have to do every thing possible on Server side to make your application safe enough.